# WCF netTcpBinding hosted on IIS7.5 Stops Working

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, net.tcp

I have a simple .NET 4 WCF service which I have hosted locally on IIS7.5. Initially I had it hosted using `httpBinding` which worked fine. Then I switched it to `netTcpBinding`, which after changing the `web.config` file accordingly was also working fine. However today it has decided to stop working. I cannot connect to the service using the test client at all, getting:

`URI: net.tcp://localhost/case/service.svc/mex    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/case/service.svc/mex'.    The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/case/service.svc/mex' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.`

I have checked that the non-http activation service is (still) installed; the net tcp listener service is running; net.tcp is in the list of enabled protocols for the site; I have run `servicemodelreg.exe -ia`; I have also re-run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`; and finally I have checked the net.tcp binding is on the site.

If I run `netstat` I can see something is listening on the port, but I cannot connect to it.

This is driving me nuts, as this morning it was working fine (as it was last week) and now it's just not.

**EDIT:** If I access the service in IE then I can see it's throwing the following exception:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

But looking in the `web.config` file that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="[REMOVED].[REMOVED]">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" contract="[REMOVED].[REMOVED]" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="PortSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="mexTcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, finally solved it. I had enabled net.tcp protocol at the site level, but it was not enabled at the application level. I guess it must have been before, and I think I might of created a new application after changing the project name earlier and obviously forgot to set the protocol on the application - doh!

So the final checklist for hosting a WCF net.tcp service on IIS is:

1. Ensure the WCF Non-HTTP Activation service is installed
2. Ensure the `Net.Tcp Listener` Service and `Net.Tcp Port Sharing` Service are both running
3. Add net.tcp to the enabled protocols for the site and the application (to access the Advanced Settings option from IIS Manager you must have an http binding present)
4. Run `servicemodelreg.exe -ia` to register WCF elements with IIS
5. Run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` to ensure .NET is setup correctly with IIS
6. Add net.tcp binding to the site

Comment: If I could give you +10 I would...  All the stuff that I read for hours today and nobody talked about making sure to enable the protocol in both places.  This question needs to be linked into all the other net.tcp-iis-don't-work threads that are out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that port sharing is enabled?

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx

EDIT - For WAS there is another service needed:

besides the `NetTcpPortSharing` the service `NetTcpActivator` is needed too...

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx

Comment: Yep, that's enabled and running.

Comment: are using WAS by any chance ?

Comment: I guess so. I've got the service hosted on IIS 7.5 (running on Win7) using net.tcp so I guess that would be using WAS.

Comment: check the link from my edit... it gives several hints for a working setup - including some permissions/rights things...